# What is a trivializing section in the context of invertible sheaves / line bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes

Assume we have a line bundle $L$ with on open cover $U_i$. What exactly does it mean for a section $s \in L(U)$ to be trivializing?

Comment: There is no 'trivializing section'. Rather, there is a cover $\{U_i\} $ of $X$,  a 'trivializing cover of the line bundle', such that $L(U_i) $ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O} _{U_i} $. Any section $s$ can be defined by specifying its restrictions to the cover, which are just elements of $\mathcal{O} _{U_i} $.

Comment: @Alvaro Martinez  thanks for your reply. I was just wondering because i stumbled on this in some papers multiple times and i was not sure what to make of it

Comment: Perhaps what was meant by "trivializing section over $U_i$" is a section $s_i \in L(U_i)$ that is the image of $1$ under a trivialization $\mathcal{O}_{U_i} \to L|_{U_i}$.